# Problem books at undergraduate level

Tags: undergraduate-education, textbooks, reference-books

I am an Undergraduate student ready to enter into Graduate School. I will be studying Mathematics. In my Undergraduate studies, I came across various Problem books and followed some of them. The results have been outstanding. I wanted to know if there are any more problem books which I missed or should follow apart from the ones listed below:

1. Problems in Mathematical Analysis by Kaczor & Nowak, Vol 1,2,3
2. Berkeley Problems in Mathematics
3. Challenging Problems in Linear Algebra by Fuzhen Zhang

Comment: I'd like to suggest more than just problem books. Many incredible textbooks have incredible exercises; Jacobson is one of my favorites for introductory algebra, and certainly many others have exercises as essential to the learning process. Atiyah-Macdonald and Hartshorne are the first that come to mind. Hatcher too, for algebraic topology.

Answer (score 11):

There are certainly many more. The following list is not meant to be exhaustive but meant just to give you a selection of the many more books that you have missed:

1. Halmos: Linear Algebra Problem Book, A Hilbert Space Problem Book.
2. George Polya and Gabor Szegö: Problems and Theorems in Analysis - I, II.
3. Ram Murty: Problems in Analytic Number Theory.
4. Jody Esmonde, Ram Murty: Problems in Algebraic Number Theory.
5. Gelbaum: Problems in Analysis, Problems in Real and Complex Analysis.
6. D. Aliprantis and O. Burkinshaw, Problems in Real Analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Following up on Mike Miller's comment that "many incredible textbooks have incredible exercises," you might want to take a look at Pugh's [Real Mathematical Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387952977) for its excellent selection of problems.

I would also also like to recommend Steele's [The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class: An Introduction to the Art of Mathematical Inequalities](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052154677X) as a book both entertaining and instructive in inequalities and problem-solving techniques.

Answer (score 2):

I like these books:

1. [Putnam and Beyond](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/book/978-0-387-25765-5) by Gelca, and Andreescu.  Brief introductions to mathematical topics from all over the curriculum and a number of competition-style problems to try.
2. [A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory](http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/frint.html) by Silverman.  The open-ended way in which the problems in this textbook are phrased, are suggestive of the kinds of questions that a researcher might has.
3. [Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/academic/product/1,4096,0201199122,00.html?type=FEA) by Grimaldi.  This is a textbook that must have more than 1000 problems, many of which are quite good, challenging and give students access to a more general theory than what is being covered in the book.

Comment: +1 for "Putnam and Beyond" alone, which is available in full after a single google: [link](http://www.cms.zju.edu.cn/UploadFiles/AttachFiles/201082333637670.pdf) (pdf 815 pages). $$ $$ I mentioned the book in an earlier answer to [MESE 10556](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/10557).